# file_get_contents теряет php переменные, если они получены из базы данных

Tags: php, sql, file-get-contents

```
$userid = $myrow[0];
$userid2 = (int)$userid;
$query = "SELECT * FROM data where data.id=".$userid2."";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$homepage = file_get_contents('https://m.com/index.php'); 
echo $homepage;
```

Страница https://m.com/index.php содержит переменные из массива $rows. Если запрос к базе данных такой *$query = "SELECT * FROM data where data.id=1";* , то $homepage корректно отображает $rows[1], если же  *$query = "SELECT * FROM data where data.id=".$userid2."";* ($userid2 - это преобразованная в число $myrow[0]), то $homepage вместо $rows[1] отображает пустоту.

$myrow[0] получена корректно, в данном случае это 1.

Comment: ничего не понятно. каша какая-то. причем тут file_get_contents, если речь идет о запросе? может быть преобразование невозможно для $myrow[0] невозможно и это ломает скрипт? сделайте вывод ошибок на экран и посмотрите ошибки

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev сначала был сделан запрос ($query), в результате которого получился массив $rows. Элементы массива отображаются, если открыть страницу в браузере. НО если эту страницу прогнать через file_get_contents и запросить содержимое, элементы не отображаются, вместо них пустота.

Comment: проверьте опцию php allow_url_fopen

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev подключила опцию через htaccess, проверила, работает. Но все равно не спасло. Тут дело вот в чем. Запрашиваешь дамп $myrow[0] (это id записи, из которой лепится $rows) - string(1) "2". Запрашиваешь после обработки file_get_contents  - NULL. Конешно id 0 в таблице data нет, поэтому и пусто. Наверное теперь надо создать другой вопрос почему file_get_contents так делает.

Comment: `file_get_contents` в данном случае возвращает скачанную из интернета страницу по протоколу `https`, PHP-код на которой выполнился еще до того, как записалась переменная `$homepage`. если файл `index.php` находится на том же сервере, что и код из шапки, то `file_get_contents('/путь/относительно/корня/ФС/к/файлу/index.php')`. если значения переменной `$rows` нужно подставить в $homepage, то `include '/путь/относительно/корня/ФС/к/файлу/index.php'`, чтоб не возится с `eval()`

Comment: @Gust  большое спасибо за участие, моя проблема заключалась в этом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306591/not-able-to-send-cookies-with-file-get-contents Решение тут же нашла, во втором ответе.

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev  большое спасибо за участие, моя проблема заключалась в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306591/not-able-to-send-cookies-with-file-get-contents Решение тут же нашла, во втором ответе.